# 'Page' object has no attribute 'site_id'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, django-cms, attributeerror, linkbutton

I am building a brand new website with Django cms and I'm using `aldryn_bootstrap3`.

When I create a link/button my site seems broken. I get:

```
File "c:\newCMS\venv37\lib\site-packages\aldryn_bootstrap3\model_fields.py", line 172, in get_link_url
    if ref_page.site_id != getattr(cms_page, 'site_id', None):
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'site_id'
```

I tried to install the multisite module (I've seen in the forum that it worked for other people...)

Then, the configuration in my `seetings.py` is:

```
from multisite import SiteID
SITE_ID = SiteID(default=1)
```

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/es/?edit&language=es

Django Version: 1.11.22
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
...
'django.contrib.sites',
'aldryn_bootstrap3',
'multisite',
'djangocms_multisite',
'MyCMS']
```

Error during template rendering:

```
In template c:\newCMS\venv37\lib\site-packages\aldryn_bootstrap3\templates\aldryn_bootstrap3\plugins\button.html, error at line 2
```

Traceback:

```
File "c:\newCMS\venv37\lib\site-packages\aldryn_bootstrap3\model_fields.py" in get_link_url
  172.             if ref_page.site_id != getattr(cms_page, 'site_id', None):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /es/
Exception Value: 'Page' object has no attribute 'site_id'
```

Comment: What version of `django-cms` and what version of `aldryn_bootstrap3`?

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file and comment lines 172/173/174 (in your case)

$ c:\newCMS\venv37\lib\site-packages\aldryn_bootstrap3\model_fields.py

```
#if ref_page.site_id != getattr(self.page, 'site_id', None):
    #ref_site = Site.objects._get_site_by_id(ref_page.site_id)
    #link = '//{}{}'.format(ref_site.domain, link)
```

Then return to the GUI and delete the 'Link-button' that caused the problem

Open the file 'model_fields.py' again and uncomment the 3 lines. Then restart your instance

$ c:\newCMS\venv37\lib\site-packages\aldryn_bootstrap3\model_fields.py

```
if ref_page.site_id != getattr(self.page, 'site_id', None):
    ref_site = Site.objects._get_site_by_id(ref_page.site_id)
    link = '//{}{}'.format(ref_site.domain, link)
```

!! This is not a definitive solution but it will allow you to make your site operational again

On a ** Debian/Ubuntu ** server, edit and comment this file

$ sudo vim  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aldryn_bootstrap3/model_fields.py

--> Raphaël Jonard | Web Performances Accelerator <--

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file: aldryn_bootstrap3/model_fields.py

Replace line 169 which looks like:

```
if ref_page.site_id != getattr(self.page, 'site_id', None):
```

with:

```
if ref_page.node.site_id != getattr(self.page.node, 'site_id', None):
```